# Removing Title Bar in PyQt5 from a New Window

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have created an application which contains a button. On the click of the button, **another window open on top of the first window. I want to remove the whole title bar (menu, minimize, maximize, and exit)**. Only want to keep the title. What I am actually expecting is for **this window to open up like a pop up window** in which I can enter crendentials and stuff. There should be a button to go back which will close this pop up window.

I have tried using `FramelessWindow`, but it does not generate the desired results. I have tried a few other things like `WA_TranslucentBackground`, etc., but that did not work as well.

The code I tried is this:
`self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint) self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)`

This causes some significant issues, like new Windows content are overlayed on the first window

**Code:**

```
class LoginWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # make window size auto adjust to the size of the widgets but with a minimum size
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.setMinimumSize(500, 500)
        # remove minimize and maximize buttons
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F8F8F8;")

        self.setup_ui()
        self.add_navigation_arrow()

    def setup_ui(self):
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        main_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        main_layout.setSpacing(20)

        username_label = QLabel("Username", self)
        username_label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))

        username_input = QLineEdit(self)
        username_input.setPlaceholderText("Enter your username")
        # fix the width of the input field
        username_input.setFixedWidth(250)

        organization_label = QLabel("Organization", self)
        organization_label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))

        organization_input = QLineEdit(self)
        organization_input.setPlaceholderText("Enter your organization name")
        organization_input.setFixedWidth(250)

        next_button = QPushButton("Next", self)
        next_button.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton {background-color: #000000; color: white; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px;}"
            "QPushButton:hover {background-color: #333333;}"
            "QPushButton:pressed {background-color: #555555;}"
        )

        main_layout.addSpacing(20)
        main_layout.addWidget(username_label)
        main_layout.addWidget(username_input)
        main_layout.addWidget(organization_label)
        main_layout.addWidget(organization_input)
        main_layout.addSpacing(20)
        main_layout.addWidget(next_button, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

    def add_navigation_arrow(self):
        back_arrow = QPushButton("←", self)
        back_arrow.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton {background-color: transparent; color: black; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;}"
            "QPushButton:hover {color: #555555;}"
        )
        back_arrow.setFixedSize(40, 40)
        back_arrow.clicked.connect(self.go_back)
        back_arrow.move(10, 10)  # Adjust the position of the arrow button

    def go_back(self):
        self.close()
        self.parent().setEnabled(True)
        self.parent().show()


class StartupWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Startup Window")
        self.setFixedSize(500, 300)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F8F8F8;")

        self.setup_ui()

    def setup_ui(self):
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        main_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        main_layout.setSpacing(20)
        main_layout.addStretch(1)

        button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        button_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        login_button = QPushButton("Login", self)
        login_button.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton {background-color: #44A147; color: white; border-radius: 10px; "
            "padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;}"
            "QPushButton:hover {background-color: #3B8548;}"
        )

        signup_button = QPushButton("Sign Up", self)
        signup_button.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton {background-color: #007BFF; color: white; border-radius: 10px; padding-left: 20px; "
            "padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;} "
            "QPushButton:hover {background-color: #0069D9;}"
        )

        exit_button = QPushButton("Close/Exit", self)
        exit_button.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton {background-color: #DC3545; color: white; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px;}"
            "QPushButton:hover {background-color: #C82333;}"
        )

        login_button.clicked.connect(self.open_login_window)

        button_layout.addWidget(login_button)
        button_layout.addSpacing(20)
        button_layout.addWidget(signup_button)

        main_layout.addLayout(button_layout)
        main_layout.addStretch(1)
        main_layout.addWidget(exit_button, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    def open_login_window(self):
        self.setEnabled(False)
        self.login_window = LoginWindow(self)
        self.login_window.show()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante I have added the minimum reproducible code!